# Visual Python using a for loop to track a changing axis?

Tags: vpython

I have a giant array that I am importing from a text file holding 200,000 values which all describe how an arrow should be traversing along the x axis.  Mx is the name of the array that I have imported from this text file.  I am using visual python to try and simulate this movement across the axes.

```
    arrow = arrow(length = 1.0,pos = (0,0,0),axis=(0,0,0),color=color.blue)
    for i in range(len(Mx)):
     rate(60)
     arrow.axis.x = Mx[i]
```

When I run my code the arrow remains stationary, and "QObject::killTimers: timers cannot be stopped from another thread" this error message pops up.  I am not sure why.  Any advice would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that this fixed it for some reason.

```
arrow = arrow(length = 1.0,pos = (0,0,0),axis=(0,0,0),color=color.blue)
for i in range(len(Mx)):
 rate(60)
 x = Mx[i]
 arrow.axis.x = x
```

Not 100 percent sure why, but I am guessing it has something to do with how python handles the array that I imported from the text file.